# Swift openURL change text of return to app and persist website login

Tags: swift, redirect

I am very new to Swift, so please excuse any mangled terminology.

In my application, the user scans a barcode which encodes a url.  I then redirect them to that website with

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success:Bool) in })
}
else
{
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
}
```

In the topleft corner of the safari browser, there is a little arrow with the name of my App.  If you click it, it returns to my app.
I'd like to change that text to "Done" rather than the name of my app.

Also, if the site I redirect them to requires a log in, that's fine.  But after they login, on the next scan, it asks them to login again.  How can I make the login persistent?

Comment: If you want done button, Don't use UIApplication.shared.open. Try this https://medium.com/@anupgupta.arg/safari-view-controller-swift-4-2e3ee2f772f4

Comment: Thank you @RajeshKumarR, that's what I found out as well.  Works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

First, app name on top left corner is default behavior of deeplinking. You can't change that to 'done'.

Second, If I got you right you can save the 'data' in cookies, session or any stateful area so that you can fetch it after login.